# 'H.length' is null or not an object PIE HTC

Tags: jquery, css3pie

Anyone know why I would be getting this PIE script error.
'H.length' is null or not an object PIE HTC

It only happens In IE8 and IE7
I'm using I'm using PIE.htc Version 1.0beta5 anyone got any ideas why this is happening.

Update:
I used PIE_uncompressed.htc to see if it would log more details and this time I get 'renderers.length' is null or not an object (line 4148)

Anyone run into this or with the uncompressed version I get 'H.length' is null or not an object.

Update:

Again I'm sorry I cant post any code but still having the issue. Has anyone out there had this error before.

Comment: Are you using the latest version (beta 5)?

Comment: You mean latest version of PIE. If so I'm using PIE.htc Version 1.0beta5

Comment: Can you post a link or sample code?

Comment: Switch temporarily to the PIE_uncompressed.htc file; since that one is not obfuscated it will give a more useful error message and line number.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not post a link due to the nature of the clients privacy. There is so much code its hard to just post a snippet. Its happening in a few different areas I use PIE. Not everywhere but a few. I used PIE_uncompressed.htc and this is what I got. 'renderers.length' is null or not an object (line 4148)

Comment: I just got the same error that you mentioned.  I updated to the 2.0beta and it resolved the error.  I was using 1.0 stable.